# from display:none to display:inline-block animation, image carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

i need a new carousel for my website, for the mobile version.
so i created one using html css and javascript, but however, the switch between the images is way too "simple".
here is the code
The HTML

```
<div class="containerr">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/nature"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/architecture"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/animals"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/tech"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
}
.containerr {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.containerr div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.containerr img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

JS

```
var currentIndex = 0,
  items = $('.containerr div'),
  itemAmt = items.length;

function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.containerr div').eq(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
  item.css('display','inline-block');
}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
}, 3000);

$('.next').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmbrWj

looking for any tip to animate/transit the display:inline-block to display:none

Comment: Animate the opacity from 0 to 1

Comment: can you be more precise please?can you provide a codepen?

Comment: display can only switch from 1 state to another, there is only one step to animate from to, where colors, opacity can be broken into almost infinite values to make a visual animation step by step along a time line. **some basics example in css** http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/CJpsd http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Hdpku or http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gbxRRM to inspire you **css value can be updated via javascript as you do of course**

Comment: thank you !! its getting clearer :D

Answer (score 0):

You can build a fade in / out effect into your `cycleItems()` function:

```
function cycleItems() {
    var visibleItem = items.filter(":visible");
    var item = $('.containerr div').eq(currentIndex);
    visibleItem.fadeOut(function() {
        item.fadeIn();
    });
}
```

The above code uses a jQuery filter to find the current visible item and calls `fadeOut()` on only that item. It then uses a callback function to execute `fadeIn()` on the current item after `fadeOut()` has completed.

Comment: unfortunately i am not allowed to use jQuery, is there a way to do this via pure JS?
     edit: it worked like a charm on codepen. thank you anyway

Comment: Your initial code is already using jQuery, is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `items.hide();`
with this `items.fadeOut("slow");`